# Create Athena tables using AWS crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am trying to create metadata tables for files stored in the S3 bucket using an AWS Glue Crawler. Below is somewhat the s3 structure looks like-

```
test_bucket/
└── test_folder1
    └── test_folder2
        └── output
            ├── file_1
            │   └── file_1.csv
            ├── file_2
            │   └── file_2.csv
            └── intermediate_files
                ├── file_11
                │   └── file_11.csv
                ├── file_12
                │   └── file_12.csv
                ├── file_21
                │   └── file_21.csv
                └── file_22
                    └── file_22.csv
```

The set configuration does create separate Athena tables for each file in the "output" directory, i.e., for file_1.csv and file_2.csv but for the "intermediate_files" directory, a partitioned table is created with files in that folder being partitioned columns.

**Actual Athena Tables**

```
file_1
file_2
intermediate_files (partitioned)
```

> **But I want to have separate tables for each intermediate file as well.**

**Expected Athena Tables**

```
file_1
file_11
file_12
file_2
file_21
file_22
```

The AWS Crawler configuration is as follows-

```
                                   Name  some_name
                            Description 
Create a single schema for each S3 path  false
                            Table level 
                 Security configuration 
                                   Tags  -
                                  State  Ready
                               Schedule 
                           Last updated  Wed Oct 13 17:32:33 GMT+530 2021
                           Date created  Wed Oct 13 15:39:12 GMT+530 2021
                               Database  some_db
                           Service role  some_role
                   Selected classifiers  csv_classifier
                             Data store  S3
                           Include path  s3://test_bucket/test_folder1/test_folder2/
                             Connection 
                       Exclude patterns 

Configuration options

       Schema updates in the data store  Update the table definition in the data catalog.
              Inherit schema from table  Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table.
      Object deletion in the data store  Mark the table as deprecated in the data catalog.
```

And, also the partitioned table created is missing few columns from some of the intermediate files.

I'm not much familiar with AWS crawlers so please let me know the crawler configuration I can set to achieve either of the two scenarios-

1. Get separate athena tables for each file in the test_customer folder
2. Or, get the missing columns in the intermediate_files partitioned table

I would really appreciate any sort of help. Thanks!

Comment: " missing few columns" - you have to provide examples of each file. What collums are missing where? What are you current crawler settings that you are using?

Comment: Hi @Marcin I have already provided the configuration that I'm using. And, the columns missing is not the main issue. The issue is that I'm not getting a separate Athena table for each intermediate file. I don't want the intermediate_files directory to get partitioned.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get a single partitioned table for `intermediate_files/` is that the files inside that directory have the same schema. I assume that the other files are different enough from each other for the crawler to determine that they need to be different tables.

You can influence how the crawler makes this decision by adding each directory under `intermediate_files/` as a separate include path for your crawler, that will tell it to make them into different tables.

I recommend reading [How Does a Crawler Determine When to Create Partitions?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-s3-folder-table-partition.html) in the Glue documentation, it has a concrete example of how to solve a similar situation.

Comment: Actually, the schema is not totally the same. Somewhat they are different, that is, there are only a few columns that are found in every file but each file is also having its own columns.

Comment: The schemas must be similar enough that the crawler thinks they are the same, otherwise it would have created separate tables.